# Update query (Parameterized query,Table valued parameters)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-update, parameterized-query, table-valued-parameters

I have a

SQL TABLE Inventory Having many columns two of which are 
LocalSKU (pk) varchar(200) NOT NULL
QOH int

And 
an EXCEL DATA having only two columns
LocalSKU and QOH

I want to implement a query where I want to match both data according to LocalSKU and if they match , The query should update QOH. If they Do not match , Do Nothing.

I've wriiten this query

```
                          SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(@"MERGE Inventory AS target
                          USING (select LocalSKU, QOH from @source)  as source
                          ON (source.LocalSKU = target.LocalSKU)
                          WHEN MATCHED THEN
                          UPDATE SET QOH = source.QOH
                                      WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
                          INSERT (QOH)
                          VALUES (source.QOH);", sqlconn);
```

It does not work. Please guide me how to implement this.

Examples will be appreciated.

Comment: why are you using merge if you only want to take an action when they match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                      SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(@"MERGE Inventory AS target
                          USING (select LocalSKU,QOH, Integer3 from @source)  as source
                          ON (source.LocalSKU = target.LocalSKU)
                         WHEN MATCHED THEN
                          UPDATE SET Integer3 = source.QOH;", sqlconn);
```